# D3 JS separation of code

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to separate out my script portion into a separate JS file.

**Current collated file:**

```
<html>
<head><title>d3 Funnel Charts</title></head>
<font face="verdana"></font>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3-funnel-charts.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javscript.js"></script>
    <div>
        <div id="Container" align="center" style="border:1px solid red" position="fixed"></div>
        <button value="APAC" onclick='ShowData(this)'>APAC</button>
        <button value="ASEAN" onclick='ShowData(this)'>ASEAN</button>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myObj = [{
        "region":"APAC",
        "customers": [
            { "name":"Total customer base", "count":2000, "value":2000 },
            { "name":"Total tier 2 customer base", "count":35 ,"value":2000},
            { "name":"Total tier 3 cusomers", "count":90 ,"value":2000}
        ]
        },
        {
        "region":"ASEAN",
        "customers": [
            { "name":"Total customer base", "count":2000, "value":2000 },
            { "name":"Total tier 2 customer base", "count":35 ,"value":2000},
            { "name":"Total tier 3 cusomers", "count":90 ,"value":2000}
        ]
        }

        ];



        function addData(Array, region) {
            console.log(Array);
            for(var i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
                if(myObj[i].region == region){
                    for(var p=0;p<myObj[i].customers.length;p++){
                        var temp=[]; 
                        temp.push(myObj[i].customers[p].name,myObj[i].customers[p].count,myObj[i].customers[p].ARR);
                        Array.push(temp);

                    }
                }

            }    

        }       

        function ShowData(objButton){  
            alert(objButton.value);
            var svg = d3.select("svg").remove();

            var dataArray=[];
            addData(dataArray,objButton.value);
            dataArray.sort(function(a,b){
                return b[1] - a[1];
            })


            var svgContainer = d3.select("Container").append("svg")
                                                .attr("width", 600)
                                                .attr("height", 500);

            svgContainer = new FunnelChart({
                        data: dataArray,
                        bottomPct: 1/2,

                        });
            svgContainer.draw('#Container', 4);//draw chart
        }           

        window.onload=function(){
            var dataArray=[];
            addData(dataArray,"APAC");

            dataArray.sort(function(a,b){
                return b[1] - a[1];
            })


            var svgContainer = d3.select("Container").append("svg")
                                                .attr("width", 600)
                                                .attr("height", 500);

            svgContainer = new FunnelChart({
                        data: dataArray,
                        bottomPct: 1/2,

                        });
            svgContainer.draw('#Container', 4);//draw chart

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**New HTML FILE**

```
`<html>
<head><title>d3 Funnel Charts</title></head>

<font face="verdana"></font>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javscript.js"></script>
    <div>
        <div id="Container" align="center" style="border:1px solid red" position="fixed"></div>
        <button value="APAC" onclick='ShowData(this)'>APAC</button>
        <button value="ASEAN" onclick='ShowData(this)'>ASEAN</button>

    </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

**NEW JS File**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3-funnel-charts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myObj = [{
        "region":"APAC",
        "customers": [
            { "name":"Total customer base", "count":2000, "ARR":2000 },
            { "name":"Handshake", "count":35 ,"ARR":2000},
            { "name":"Customer Kick off", "count":90 ,"ARR":2000}
        ]
        },
        {
        "region":"ASEAN",
        "customers": [
            { "name":"Total customer base", "count":2578,"ARR":2000 },
            { "name":"Handshake", "count":1500 ,"ARR":2000},
            { "name":"Customer Kick off", "count":1200 ,"ARR":2000 },
            { "name":"Hands On or Use Case Adoption Workshop", "count":1000 ,"ARR":2000 },
            { "name":"Use Case Agreed/WIP/Implemented", "count":976 ,"ARR":2000 },
            { "name":"Use Case WIP/Implemented", "count":580 ,"ARR":2000 },
            { "name":"Use Case Implemented", "count":211 ,"ARR":2000 },
            { "name":"Permanenet Use Case Implemented", "count":190 ,"ARR":2000 }
        ]
        }

        ];



        function addData(Array, region) {
            console.log(Array);
            for(var i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
                if(myObj[i].region == region){
                    for(var p=0;p<myObj[i].customers.length;p++){
                        var temp=[]; 
                        temp.push(myObj[i].customers[p].name,myObj[i].customers[p].count,myObj[i].customers[p].ARR);
                        Array.push(temp);

                    }
                }

            }    

        }       

        function ShowData(objButton){  
            alert(objButton.value);
            var svg = d3.select("svg").remove();

            var dataArray=[];
            addData(dataArray,objButton.value);
            dataArray.sort(function(a,b){
                return b[1] - a[1];
            })


            var svgContainer = d3.select("Container").append("svg")
                                                .attr("width", 600)
                                                .attr("height", 500);

            svgContainer = new FunnelChart({
                        data: dataArray,
                        bottomPct: 1/2,

                        });
            svgContainer.draw('#Container', 4);//draw chart
        }           

        window.onload=function(){
            var dataArray=[];
            addData(dataArray,"APAC");

            dataArray.sort(function(a,b){
                return b[1] - a[1];
            })


            var svgContainer = d3.select("Container").append("svg")
                                                .attr("width", 600)
                                                .attr("height", 500);

            svgContainer = new FunnelChart({
                        data: dataArray,
                        bottomPct: 1/2,

                        });
            svgContainer.draw('#Container', 4);//draw chart

        }
    </script>
```

However, this doesnt seem to work. Any suggestions on what i am doing wrong on the separation of the JS and HTMl files?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have script imports inside a Javascript file. They should be in your HTML file.

The `<script>` tag is a HTML construct; it's not part of the Javascript syntax.

Answer (score 0):

HTML should be as follows:

`

```html
<html>
<head><title>d3 Funnel Charts</title></head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javscript.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3-funnel-charts.js"></scrip

<body>

<!-- remove this <font face="verdana"></font>//-->
```

.js file should begin here

```js
var myObj = [{
```

since the src = has to /path/to/file make sure you js files are in the same directory as your file which is referencing them